# Go言語で指定文字列を置換　(複数テキストファイル対象)

Tags: go

Go言語で指定のディレクトリ配下のテキストファイル(再帰的に探索)して、指定した文字列に置換するプログラムを作ったのですが、入力した文字列(ここだとbefore,after)
を関数visitで利用できるようにするにはどうしたらいいかご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

```golang
newContents := bytes.Replace(read, before, after, -1)
```

のところで使いたいのですが、使えるようにする手段がわからず、困っています。

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func visit(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if !!fi.IsDir() {
        return nil //
    }

    matched, err := filepath.Match("*.txt", fi.Name())

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if matched {
        read, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(path)
        newContents := bytes.Replace(read, before, after, -1)
        err = ioutil.WriteFile(path, newContents, os.ModePerm)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    root := input("ファイルパス")
    before := input("置換前文字列")
    after := input("置換後文字列")
    err := filepath.Walk(root, visit)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func input(msg string) string {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print(msg + ":")
    scanner.Scan()
    return scanner.Text()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 入力した文字列(ここだと `before`, `after`)を関数 `visit` で利用できるようにするにはどうしたらいいか

以下は closure(クロージャ)を使う方法です。

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func input(msg string) string {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print(msg + ":")
    scanner.Scan()
    return scanner.Text()
}

func replaceFileContents(path string, before, after []byte) error {
    read, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fmt.Println(path)
    if bytes.Contains(read, before) {
        newContents := bytes.Replace(read, before, after, -1)
        err = ioutil.WriteFile(path, newContents, os.ModePerm)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    root := input("ファイルパス")
    before := []byte(input("置換前文字列"))
    after := []byte(input("置換後文字列"))

    err := filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if fi.IsDir() || filepath.Ext(fi.Name()) != ".txt" {
            return nil
        }

        return replaceFileContents(path, before, after)
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。おかげで実現したい処理ができました。
追加で置き返したファイルの数を最後に表示する処理を加えようとしたのですが、、

Comment: 上の追記した２つ目の質問のように手詰まってしまいます。。